# How to use WinMerge with "Github for Windows"

Tags: github-for-windows, winmerge

I use "Github for Windows" as the git client (and use it with an enterprise github server). Is it possible to configure using WinMerge to be used with this client? I have not seen a setting for setting up any GUI diff tool for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C:\Users"name of user" folder open file .gitconfig and write

```
[merge]
tool = winmerge
[mergetool]
prompt = false
keepBackup = false
keepTemporaries = false
[mergetool "winmerge"]
name = WinMerge
trustExitCode = true
cmd = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"     >/dev/null 2>&1"
keepBackup=false
```

Then,

- restart github desktop,
- in left pannel :
- select repository :
- right click : Open in Command Prompt.
- When the command prompt appears type: `git mergetool`

If it doesn't work, try : `git mergetool –tool=winmerge`

Comment: And once you have done this, how do you use WinMerge from the Github for Windows GUI?

Comment: @GustavDelius In github desktop : select repository : right click : Open in Command Prompt. When the command prompt appears type:

``git mergetool``      
If it doesn't work, try :  
``git mergetool –tool=winmerge``